# Why NPM install command removes my previously installed packages in React-native?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

[this is the NPM install result, where it removed my 317 packages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzTAO.png)

Comment: Are you getting any import error after running `npm install` command. If no then it's fine. No need to worry. If yes, please check the package you installed is added to `package.json` file under `dependencies`.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  (*[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may help.) In fact you're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] **as text** so that we can test and debug your problem.